# Can my home's concrete slab bear the weight of a 20,000 lb. aquarium?

Tags: flooring

I am buying a very large fish tank for the house. And would like to know if the house can interior slab can hold up to 20,000lbs

Comment: This question is impossible to answer with the information provided. Slab thickness, internal reinforcement, foundation type, soil base, and other factors need to be considered (by a qualified engineer). Also, does "can hold" allow for cracking?

Comment: Very large would be better qualified by dimensions as well. It's possible that your concrete would tolerate a fish tank that was the size of a two-car garage, as the weight would be distributed over quite a large area, but if the tank was a vertical cylinder of a meter or two, it would be quite concentrated.

Comment: Really? A 2000+ gallon aquarium?  2000*8.34=16,680lbs.

Comment: Shape matters as well, for this "just shy of 2400 gallon" hypothetical aquarium. 320 cubic feet of water... Is it deep or shallow? Shallow causes less loading per square foot, deep more. If the "house interior slab" was designed with such a load in mind, that's one thing. If not, it's another.

Comment: Is it 2000 or 20,000 gals.?

Comment: Does 20,000 lb include the weight of the whales that will be swimming in it?

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be installed on the ground floor, there are only a couple of things you need to check: 1) soil bearing value, and 2) size of aquarium.

1) Because your concrete slab is resting on the ground, the "load" of the aquarium on the concrete is in compression ONLY, (until it settles.) The reason your slab would settle is because there is too much load on the soil. (We don't worry so much about the concrete because even crappy concrete can withstand 1-2000 lbs. per square inch.)

However, the soil can only withstand 1500 lbs. per square foot, unless you live in a swamp, like me. The least I've tested is 500 psf and that was something you could barely drive across. The least I'd use is 1500 psf.

2) If your aquarium is about 24" wide and 8' long, the soil bearing would be: 20,000 lbs. / 2' x 8' = 1,250 per square foot, well below the 1500 allowed by code without a geotechnical investigation and within the limits of normal soil bearing capabilities.

If you live in a swampy area, all this could change. Otherwise, I think you're fine. (However, make sure the aquarium spreads the load out evenly. No legs on the aquarium stand concentrating the load at each leg.)

Comment: Oops...gallons v. Lbs.  You're still okay.

Comment: Oops...no wait. At 20,000 gals. That will equal 166,800 lbs.  So, how big of footprint is that aquarium?

Comment: The OP states 20,000 lb which is 2400 gal or 320 ft^3. We need to know the L, W, and D ; but say L= 10', W = 5', D = 6' gives a loading pressure of 400 lb/sq ft

Comment: @JimStewart oh, yes...lbs.  I think I panicked and went from lbs. to gallons. Yes, the slab should be fine...unless there's something very unusual about the aquarium.